# Is it possible to use a network printer without installing any driver? How

Tags: networking, drivers, printing, printer

I´ve a shared printer on Raspbian and I want to use from my Windows 8.1 without install any driver on the Windows OS.

I can see the printer, but when I try to configure it, windows is asking for the driver.

I read that it´s possible to use a network printer using postcript, but I don´t know how. Is that correct? How should Windows be configured?

Comment: You will need to install a driver since W8.1 does not have a generic one for it.

Comment: AFAIK windows in general needs a driver to print...

Comment: @moab surely you can install any simple printer which supports PostScript printing and comes bundled with the OS? L(I used to use a LaserJet 5 - although I don't think that even does PostScript). Of-course, you loose some of the functionality of the printer that way.

Comment: @davidgo then tell us how to do it.

Comment: I have not used Windows 8 - only Windows 7 (and Linux) to do this kind of thing. You manually configure a network printer - I do it by setting printer/Pi with a static/unchanging IP address and then browse existing drivers and find a classic - like HP LaserJet 5.

Comment: You can send text files directly to the printer if it supports PCL5. For anything more complex, a driver is needed to create a file with the printer commands.

Comment: Could you explain how could I send a text file that I can’t install?

Comment: You can send the text file to the printer's IP address using LPR. In Control Panel, go to "Turn windows features on or off" and make sure "Print and document services" are installed. Then use "lpr -S printer_IP -P raw filename" from a DOS prompt